# Create a workflow that sends an email when all of the "BU Columns" have been completed

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

[image]I have a list in SharePoint 2013 with multiple columns. I want to send an email when all of the columns that apply (19 columns out of 41 columns) have been completed. I have created a workflow but when I test it an email is not sent. enter image description here[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your image doesn't display all your workflow, but you must consider a couple of things:

1. Are you sure you have set-up correctly the email in SharePoint?
2. In the workflow, you **must** have a loop that will only stop unless those 19 columns have been filled (add a wait 5 minutes time). In order to achieve this, you must have 19 boolean variables. Each variable represent a column. So, once a column is filled, a variable corresponding a column will become to `True`. Once all 19 variable are `True`, loop will break, and the email will be sent.

Comment: I added 19 boolean variables. It is still not working correctly. The first problem is I have another workflow that sends an email when a new initiative has been added. Even though the Initiative column is not included in my BU Column workflow, when I add a new initiative I receive two emails, one for the New Initiative workflow and one for the BU Columns Completed workflow. Also the idea is to send an email only when these 19 columns have been updated but it sends an email when anything is updated. Here is an example of what I have:

Comment: If Current Item:Current Phase (Workflow) not equals Current Item:Current Phase
 Set Variable: CurrentPhaseUpdated to Yes
 Set Current Phase (Workflow) to Current Item:Current Phase